# grep exact string from file shell

Tags: shell, grep

I have a host file with two lines:

1.1.1.1 host

1.2.3.4 host-MY

I'd like to grep the line contains **host** string only (not the other line that contain host-MY)

I use: grep -x host /etc/hosts
but -x search whole line matching 
Thanks in advance

Comment: So, what is the output you would like to get given the above two strings as input?

Comment: Maxim , I'd like to get 0 if exists , 1 -if not

Comment: I added -q option to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: dashes are considered as word separator.
Try this one instead:

```
grep -E '(^|[[:space:]])host($|[[:space:]])' /etc/hosts
```

---

Old post:

You can use:

```
grep -w host /etc/hosts
```

This works fine on Solaris with `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep`.

The portable version would be:

```
grep -E '\<host\>' /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Thanks Benoit, this expression bring two lines or more , but I'd like to get line that contain my exact string .

Comment: Thanks Benoit, looks like your expression doing the work , could you explain please how it's working ?

Comment: It's grepping your word, with either a space or beginning of line before and a space or end of line after it.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I understand why need ^,$ and word :space: , but why double square brackets needed ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
grep -q -E "\bhost\b" /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
grep -E "\s*host\s*$" /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Thanks sjngm ,As I understand this regex will find string in the end of line , but in my case the string can be in the middle of the line too like:    1.1.1.1 host another_host